# Worst Abuse of CSS?

Tags: popularity-contest, css

What is some of the coolest/best/worse abuses of CSS?

For example, [these shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), or using multiple box-shadows to make pixel art.

[popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) ending on 16/04/14.

Comment: Using it inline in `style` attributes *and* adding `!important` to each one.

Comment: How do you define an *abuse*? I'm off-topic but thanks for the link with inspiring shapes.

Comment: @n.1 Something that was clearly not intended when the specifications were made.

Comment: This question doesn't comply with the [rules](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The Internet...

Comment: You should accept some answer :)

Comment: @user80551: Post as an answer, I'd vote for that :D

Answer (score 13):

Some dude created a tool to convert any image to pure CSS. This goes well beyond the original intent of CSS.

Here is an example (The famous Mona Lisa):
http://codepen.io/jaysalvat/pen/HaqBf

And here is the tool :
https://github.com/jaysalvat/image2css

Comment: Holy virgin mother of god! That is quite a great tool when you make a gradient background and you (for some reason) don't have the code near you and you need it.

Answer (score 13):

### Changing images on the fly

I won't necessarily call it abuse, but you can use CSS to replace an `IMG` with a given `SRC` to show a completely different image.

```
@media print
{
    IMG
    {
        padding: 150px 200px 0px 0px; 
        background: url('lady.jpg'); 
        background-size:auto; 
        width:0px; height: 0px;
    }
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css

Can be lots of fun combined with `@media` selectors to display completely different images when printing a webpage. (Same trick can be done in `PDF` btw. Nice to see the face of the guy that is printing a document and all serious looking charts are replaced by beautiful ladies :))

Comment: +1 For cruel but ingenious ways of paying back on colleagues... Not that I would do it of course...

Comment: best use i've seen with img{background-image} was embedding an animated gif with a jpg background

Answer (score 1):

## Resizable elements:

You can add `resize:both` to allow an element to be resized by the user.
On some browsers, this is only supported on `<textarea>`'s.

## Real-time CSS preview:

This is not an actual css thing, but you can add the `contenteditable` property, add the property `style="display:block;z-index:99;width:500px;height:500px;resizable:both;"` and you can edit your CSS.

## Styled CSS Checkboxes/radiobuttons:

Using the following piece of markup as example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_all" name="check_all" value="1">
<label for="check_all">Check all</label>
```

You can use `display:none` on the `<input>` and, using CSS3 selectors, you can set a 'sprite' background to show the different states of the checkbox/radiobutton.

The order of the elements is important, and matching the `for=""` property with the `id=""` in the input is even more important!

You can see some examples here: http://www.csscheckbox.com/

## Browser specific selectors:

We all have tried to use some sort of javascript mix with css classes and media-queries...

Well, here are a **few** browser specific selectors:

```css
doesnotexist:-o-prefocus, #selector {}/*opera only*/
:root {}/*target all css3 browsers*/
:-moz-any(*){}/*mozilla and mozilla based only*/
:-webkit-any(*){}/*webkit only*/
```

For IE, you have tons of selectors. No need for more.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends what you mean by abuse but this would drive your users batty:

## Jitters

```
*:hover{
  zoom:99%;
}
```

(as you mouse around the page everything jitters on you)

## Experts-Exchange/Pay-To-View Effect

```
*{
  color:transparent;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

(makes all the text blurry)

## "Animated GIF's" using CSS sprite sheets

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/

(Java's "The Dude" waving his hand)